# Cucumber/Webdriver testing Drupal with Node

Tags: php, node.js, testing, selenium, drupal

Does anyone know how to use a test suite written in Node.js to test a Drupal, so php, site?

I want to build one test suite (and thus a site specification) which can be used to test the suitability of various platforms (some Node), and I want it to be in Node (probably selenium/webdriver and cucumber).

Is this possible? Desirable?